# d3/dc.js yAxis combine elasticY with a minValue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Is it possible to combine elasticY with a minValue?

i would like to let the maxValue of the yAxis calculate automatic, but the minValue should be fixed - is this possible?